# Is there any way to see the raw request sent by httpclient?

Tags: java, httpclient, multipart

Recently, I intend to mock a operation on a website using `HttpClient`.

When I catch the post request via `chrome developer tools`, The `content-type` is of `multipart/form-data`, so I'm trying to construct a `MultiPartEntity` to realise it. But I've always got 403 Forbidden. At this scenario, I'm sure that my cookie is of login-state, and I've tried doing other operations successfully.

So I'd like to know how to spy the raw request sent by `httpclient` so that I can compare it with the real one. Thanks a lot!

**P.S.**
Among all of the multiparts, there is one which shows as below:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_empty"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I tried to using `FileBody` to represent this part. But as you can see, the filename as well as the content is empty. If I pass a new File("") to `FileBody`, it'll throw an exception indicating that file cannot be found. So right now, I'm just using this code:

```
multiPartEntity.addPart("media_empty", new FileBody(new File("C:\\Users\\zhudi.zd\\Desktop\\BeCJToRCMAA5SdV.jpg-large"), "application/octet-stream"));
```

Hope it'll show some clues to solving this problem.

**FYI** Here's the request information come from Chrome Dev Tools as well as my equivalent code snippet:

```
--Request Headers--
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:50305
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Cookie:XXXXXX
Host:upload.twitter.com
Origin:https://target.com
Referer:https://target.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36

--Request Payload--
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post_authenticity_token"
　
199465e69ee
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="iframe_callback"
　
window.top.swift_tweetbox_1393907901862
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="in_reply_to_status_id"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="impression_id"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="earned"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="page_context"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_data[]"
　
ABCDEF
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_empty"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place_id"
　
　
------WebKitFormBoundarySYkKonqDITW7A9Bv--
```

Equivalent code snippet of mine:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("post_authenticity_token", new StringBody(loginRequest.getAuthenticity_token()));
entity.addPart("iframe-callback", new StringBody("window.top.swift_tweetbox_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
entity.addPart("in-reply-to-status-id", new StringBody(""));
entity.addPart("impression-id", new StringBody(""));
entity.addPart("earned", new StringBody(""));
entity.addPart("page-context", new StringBody(""));
entity.addPart("status", new StringBody("some text here"));
entity.addPart("media_data[]", new StringBody("ABCDEF"));
entity.addPart("media_empty", new FileBody(new File("C:\\1.jpg"), "application/octet-stream"));  // trick part, I don't know how to set it as empty file
entity.addPart("place_id", new StringBody(""));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://target.com/post");
post.setHeaders(...);//set all the headers posted above except the Content-Type, for multipartEntity will handle it automatically.
post.setEntity(entity);

response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a miserable time with this on Android. You can use [WebScarab](https://owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab) to intercept browser/website communications (and you can choose to see the raw bytes as well). Basically, you set up a local proxy in your browser. It's a nice little solution.

Note that if you're using the `MultipartEntityBuilder` from Apache HTTP Tools, you have to chain the `addPart()` methods together since they each return a new `MulitpartEntityBuilder`, as in the following code:

```
    mpeb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addTextBody("action", "upload")
                .addPart("repo_upload_file", fbp.getBody())
                .addTextBody("sesskey", jso.getString("sesskey"))
                .addTextBody("repo_id", "3")
                .addTextBody("itemid", jso.getString("itemid"))
                .addTextBody("author",  jso.getString("author"))
                .addTextBody("savepath", "/")
                .addTextBody("title", current_filename);
```

Comment: How can I use `WebScarab` to detect the output from `HttpClient`?

Comment: I see that I misunderstood the posting. Sorry. I'm going to look into this. If I don't find anything, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It looks like you can connect through a proxy. See here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e473

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using `ByteArrayEntity`, which sends the raw data that is intercepted by Chrome Dev Tools. And it has worked fine by now.